# Template Compilation

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Can someone pelase explain to me how I can avoid the error below?

I think I am following all I have read on template compilation but still get an error. Sorry for asking this - it seems trivial but I am stuck!

Thanks,
Paolo

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BitsAndPieces, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  NonTemplateFunctionFriend_main.cpp
1>NonTemplateFunctionFriend_main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Paolo<int>::getMyOnlyMember(void)" (?getMyOnlyMember@?$Paolo@H@@QAEHXZ)
1>\\na-13\agnolucp\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\BitsAndPieces\Release\BitsAndPieces.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**main**

```
#include "NonTemplateFunctionFriend.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() { 
    Paolo<int> Me;
    cout << Me.getMyOnlyMember() << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

**NonTemplateFunctionFriend.h**

```
#ifndef NonTemplateFunctionFriend_H
#define NonTemplateFunctionFriend_H

    #include <iostream>

    template<class T> class Paolo {

    private:
        T myOnlyMember;
    public:
        Paolo(): myOnlyMember(1000) {};
        T getMyOnlyMember();
    };

    #include "NonTemplateFunctionFriend.cpp"

#endif
```

**NonTemplateFunctionFriend.cpp**

```
#ifndef NonTemplateFunctionFriend_CPP
#define NonTemplateFunctionFriend_CPP

    #include "NonTemplateFunctionFriend.h"

    template<class T>   T getMyOnlyMember() {
            return myOnlyMember;
    }


#endif
```

Comment: Please format your error message as a code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the file as long as you're including it inside the header file (templates must be fully defined within the same translation unit, lacking proper support for the export keyword).

But you're not qualifying your function definition with the class

```
Paolo<T>::
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef NonTemplateFunctionFriend_H
#define NonTemplateFunctionFriend_H

    #include <iostream>

    template<class T> class Paolo {

    private:
        T myOnlyMember;
    public:
        Paolo(): myOnlyMember(1000) {};
        T getMyOnlyMember();
    };

   template<class T>
   T Paolo<T>::getMyOnlyMember() {
            return myOnlyMember;
    }


#endif
```

Comment: @RTS - I was aware taht it would work this way but I woudl liek to put them in different files (as above) so as to learn how to organize my code

Comment: @Paolo Rossi With templates good form says that you should have your function definition in the same file as the declaration. This is one of the few exceptions to the rule about keeping declaration separate from definition. This is due to the compiler and the C++ standard requiring that each templates definition be available in every compilation unit(generally a file) that the template is used in.

Comment: @Paolo Rossi: You actually cannot compile that as it is an abstract definition lacking at least the size of the `T` datastructure

Comment: @RTS - Hi again, I appreciate that but the book I am studying off talks about inclusion compilation model which implies structuring the code as I did above, although without getting errors I guess!! Thansk anyway

Comment: @Paolo Does it contain any samples of separating declaration of a template and its definition? BTW is it mentioning the `export` keyword? :-)

Comment: @RTS - it has example and it doesnt mention export - the book is called C++ a primer by Lippman, Lajoie and Moo  EXAMPLE HEADER  // header file (I omit the guards) template <class T> int compare (const T&, const T&) ;  #include "utilities.cc"     EXAMPLE SOURCE here goes teh definition of template <class T> int compare (const T&, const T&)

Comment: It's considered normal to inline template definitions in the header for the reason RTS mentioned. If that book is large and has a blue cover I believe I had it as a college text and didn't find it very good.

Comment: you refer to another book with a similar title - this one has a white cover and a paint roll on it - thanks

Comment: @RTS: That definition is fine if it happens to be used in only one file. The linker will not like it at all if multiple source files both use `Paulo<T>::getMyOnlyMember` for the same type `T`. The solution is to use the `inline` qualifier.

Comment: @RTS: To be precise the standard only requires the definition of the templates that gets instantiated. The difference is important in that for a member functions, if only the declaration is present, the template will not be instantiated, but the program is not ill formed as long as at least one translation unit does contain the instantiation of the template with the same parameters. There are a few cases where that is used to reduce compilation times, if the set of instantiating types is known and limited, you can provide the definitions in a single translation unit and explicitly instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

Template code must be *defined* before use, not just declared.

Comment: hello by #including "NonTemplateFunctionFriend.h" which then #including "NonTemplateFunctionFriend.cpp" am I not defining the template??

Comment: If it would be compilable, it could be linked to. Thus the definition won't be needed at compile time. And yes, it's hypothetical.

Comment: Paolo the compiler will generate the code for the templates based on the instantiations using the template usually found elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a free function in NonTemplateFunctionFriend.cpp, not a member function of `Paolo<T>`:

```
    template<class T>   T Paolo<T>::getMyOnlyMember() {
            return myOnlyMember;
    }
```

That is, you missed the **`Paolo<T>::`** in the definition.

Comment: That is definitely true - thnaks, but I copied the code you wrote and still get thw same error message

Comment: I got rid of return 1 in the main, re-run the code and it worked. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: return 0 to terminate normally ... non zero returns from main can be used to signal abnormal termination.

Answer (score 0):

Paolo: Your code doesn't link because your code does not define the member function `Paulo::getMyOnlyMember. You do have a definition in NonTemplateFunctionFriend.cpp that looks somewhat like what you want, but to the compiler it is a completely different function template.

That said, *never* do this in a header:

```
#include "NonTemplateFunctionFriend.cpp"
```

*Never* do this in a header, either:

```
template<class T>
T Paolo<T>::getMyOnlyMember() {
    return myOnlyMember;
}
```

The problem here is that if multiple files include the header and create a getMyOnlyMember for the same type you will have an unhappy linker. Add the `inline` qualifier and everything will be cool.